# Is there a way to include a control variable in an internal meta-analysis with metafor?

Tags: controls, effect, metafor

I am trying to conduct an internal meta-analysis with 12 studies, which include both scale and binary DVs. In all of the studies with a binary DV, we control for a variable in the main analyses. Is there a way to control for a variable when conducting a meta-analysis with metafor? What is the best way to conduct this analysis? Is there a way to calculate the effect sizes (Cohen's d) for the binary studies controlling for the variable? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I calculated the effect size (Cohen's d) for each study and used metafor to conduct an internal meta-analysis without controlling for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could fit the logistic regression model with the IV of interest and the covariate that you want to control for. The coefficient for the IV of interest is the 'adjusted' log odds ratio (let's call this lnor), which you could convert to a d-value, either using y = sqrt(3) / pi * lnor (where pi is the mathematical constant pi) or y = lnor / 1.65. The former assumes that the dichotomous outcome is a dichotomized version of a continuous variable that follows a logistic distribution, while the latter assumes a normal distribution. The corresponding sampling variance of y is 3 / pi^2 * SE[lnor]^2 or SE[lnor]^2 / 1.65^2, where SE[lnor] is the standard error of lnor (which you can extract from the logistic regression model).